# django-filters using ModelChoiceFilter to get value of ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

I'm trying to use ModelChoiceFilter to filter a database of letters based on the author. Author is a ForeignKey, and I can't seem to get it to display the "name" value of the ForeignKey.

Here is what I have:

models.py (limited to relevant bits)

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Full Name')
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Letter(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='author', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Letter Author')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='recipient', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Recipient')
    ...
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Title of Letter')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

letter_filters.py

```
class LetterFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ...
    author = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Letter.objects.order_by('author__name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Letter
        fields = ['author', 'recipient']
```

I can see that this kind of works. It is indeed limiting and ordering it properly, but instead of the author name being presented in the select box, it's presenting  "title" from the letter (but I can tell from the title, in the proper order).

What I thought should work is this:

```
fields = ['author__name', 'recipient']
```

But that too continues to list "title" from Letter instead of "name" from Person.

I know it has what I need, because if I do:

```
 author = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Letter.objects.order_by('author__name').values('author__name'))
```

I get exactly what I want! But, it's presented as {'author__name':'Jane Doe'} with fields author or author_name. I just can't seem to get the right syntax.

Finally, I know I can do:

```
author = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Person.objects.order_by('name'))
```

Which returns all Persons, properly ordered. However there are many more persons in the database than just authors. This is the same result as just allowing the default fields['author'... without setting the author= in the class (though unordered).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the queryset you specify deals with `Letter`s, so as a result the `Letter`s are in that cases added in the `ModelChoiceFiler`, which is not ideal at all.

You can however generate a list of `Person`s that has written at least one letter like:

```
django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
    queryset=Person.objects.filter(letter_set__isnull=False).order_by('name').distinct()
)
```

So here we filter on the fact that the `letter_set` is not empty, and since this will result in a JOIN where a `Person` can occur multiple times, we add `.distinct()` to it.

I find this modeling however very weird (in your three examples). It basically means that you only can assign `Person`s that already wrote a `Letter`. What if a person that has never written a `Letter` wants to write a `Letter`?

Usually in case there are different such roles, you can for example add a `BooleanField`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Full Name')
    is_author = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Is the person an author')
    # ...
```

Then we can filter on `Person`s that are `Author`s:

```
django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
    queryset=Person.objects.filter(is_author=True).order_by('name')
)
```

Comment: Oh my, thank you so incredibly much for that fast response.

Comment: Oops, enter returns comment...

As I was saying, 

` author = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Person.objects.filter(author__isnull=False).order_by('name').distinct())`

worked perfectly. I am embarrassed to admit how long I've been banging my head with that.

The context is a website I am building for my father who collect letters. He adds letters, and so all Persons exist only as a result of being an Author or Recipient of a letter. That said, I can create new Persons and haven't had any trouble connecting existing persons to Letters. I will look into your suggestion. Thanks